# Nginx subdomain 404

Tags: nginx, wordpress

(I apologize in advance for the amount of config in this post. I've been messing with this for several hours and I'm fairly new to Nginx, so I didn't want to exclude something that was potentially relevant.)

I'm attempting to host multiple Wordpress sites on a single Ubuntu server (Linode, if that makes a difference). I'm using Nginx. The primary domain is working fine, but every request to the subdomain returns a 404.

The config—which I mostly boosted from [Wordpress' documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)—is laid out thusly:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` is the main config file. Here are the contents:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    #tcp_nopush on;
    #tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;


    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Upstream PHP
    ##

    upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/global/wordpress.conf` is included at the top of my entry in `sites-available` and looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

        index index.php;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi.conf;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
#                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/global/wp-restrictions.conf` is this:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}
# robots.txt fallback to index.php
location = /robots.txt {
# Some WordPress plugin gererate robots.txt file
    allow all;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args @robots;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location @robots {
   return 200 "User-agent: *\nDisallow: /wp-admin/\nAllow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php\n";
}


location ~ /\.(?!well-known\/) {
    deny all;
}

location /wp-content/uploads {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}


location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}
```

Here's the entry for the primary domain in `sites-available`. This one works fine:

```
server {

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name mydomain.site www.mydomain.site;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

And here's the subdomain entry that's giving me the 404:

```
server {

    include global/wordpress.conf;
    include global/wp-restrictions.conf;

    server_name sub.mydomain.site;

    root /var/www/microsites/lgw/;

    index index.php;
}
```

Things I've done to confirm this *should* work:

- Subdomain's DNS is configured properly.
- Doc root for the subdomain a) exists and b) has files in it. If I try to visit any of the files by name, I get the 404.
- php-fpm is working.
- None of the domain or directory names are misspelled
- I've restarted nginx after each configuration change
- The error log only shows errors if I have `debug` turned on. Otherwise, I get bupkis when I issue requests that come back as 404.

Not sure what else to include here. According to every how-to I've been able to find, this should work. But it doesn't.

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated. And please let me know if there's additional info I can provide that would make answering this easier.

Thanks!

Comment: In your main config you have `upstream php { server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock; server 127.0.0.1:9000; }`. In your primary domain config you have `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`. What ports or sockets your php-fpm is really listen? Does php scripts working correctly on your primary site?

Comment: @IvanShatsky; php is working fine on the primary domain; I have a simple phpinfo(); call that produces the expected result.

Comment: Your php files are processed differently on your main site and on your WP sites. Try to replace `fastcgi_pass php;` with `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` in your `wordpress.conf` file. Would this getting to work at least a simple `phpinfo();`?

Comment: I do not see a `root` directive in your non-working `server` block, which explains the 404 response. And in your `upstream` block you need to choose one and comment the other one out.